# Review audit failure for answer with a link

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

In this audit - https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/12654192 
the link in answer is not a link to some external solution, but is itself a solution. Answer seems to have been deleted due to being short and containing a link.

The question has an answer with 7 upvotes that suggests basically the same, but without a CDN and with obvious `<script src=` around the link. Why should we flag such answers as unsalvageable, which is implied by audit result?

Comment: Since I left a comment there, let me say that it isn't obvious at all that it just needs `<script src=` around (it may be to you, but not to everyone). To me, it looked like *include some code from [link]*, and this is probably what it looked like to the reviewers also. With such an addition, I definitely agree with you that it shouldn't be deleted. I have edited the answer, removed my comment, and voted to undelete it.

Comment: Also, note that there is (unfortunately) no direct context inside the Low Quality Review Queue, so it is very easy to miss that there is another answer saying basically the same thing.